# how to log in springboot at different lever of log based on environment specific config yml files

Tags: spring-boot, logging, yaml, appender

I have an application which is in spring-boot in which we are logging logs at Info and for more details at debug level. Also we have environment specific config files such as application-dev.yml, application-prod.yml, application-qa.yml, etc files. Now I want to log the logs at DEBUG level in dev environment and at INFO level in prod environment . what can I add in environment specific files to achieve this?

Currently we have one logback.xml which we configured to log the logs. But we want to add configs to environment specific yaml file

Comment: `logging.level.root=DEBUG` if you want to enable for the whole app, `logging.level.<package_name>=DEBUG` if you want to enable for specific package. `logging.config` if you want to use `logback.xml`. Anything you need will be under `logging`.

Comment: @StefanGolubović I have deleted my logback.xml file. and added logging.level.root=DEBUG in my dev specific yaml file and logging.level.root=TRACE in qa specific yaml file. but still its logging at info level. its not reading logging configuration from yaml file. Why so?

Comment: post your `pom.xml`, maybe you're missing some dependency...

Comment: @StefanGolubović Resolved the issue by providing this syntax in yaml file - logging.config:classpath : logback-lowerenv.xml